# mne_browse_raw (Python MNE): How can I access user interface?

Tags: python, mne-python

How can I access the user interface of mne_browse_raw as shown [in this link](http://martinos.org/mne/dev/manual/gui/browse.html#the-user-interface)? When I type the command, for example,

```
$ mne browse_raw --raw test_raw.fif
```

I get

> Opening raw data file C:\Users\Nico\schotest_raw.fif...
>
> Isotrak not found
>
> Range : 0 ... 12900863 =      0.000 ... 25196.998 secs
>
> Ready.
>
> Adding average EEG reference projection.
>
> 1 projection items deactivated

And this view:

[image]

which doesn't have half the options as the layout shown in the link above. Am I lacking some additional parameter or something or could it be that the MNE programmers changed the layout of mne_browse_raw?

It is extremely hard to navigate through this simplified layout.

Answer (score 1):

There are several 'flavors' of MNE. There is the C version you operate from the command line. There is a Python version that includes a lot more stuff, but is generally accessed from an IPython session. Finally, there is a also a MATLAB toolbox.

The user interface you want is from the C version. So install [this version](http://martinos.org/mne/stable/install_mne_c.html) and you should have acces to the `mne_browse_raw` command.